# Rails update_all with hstore

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-postgresql, hstore

What's a good way to update multiple records with hstore columns using activerecord? Right now I'm looping through, updating and saving like this:

```
time = Time.now.to_s
scoped_tasks.each do |task|
  task.data[:last_checked] = time
  task.save!
end
```

Is there any way to do this with an `update_all` query? One solution I've seen looks like this:

```
MyModel.update_all(:properties => ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore.dump({'a' => 1}))
```

But the problem with that is it overwrites the entire column, so other values are lost. I've also seen this:

```
MyModel.update_all("data = data || hstore('a', 'blah')")
```

But for some reason I get back `0` for the value. It also looks like it will only work if the hstore is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I struggled with the same question myself, here is how I was able to solve it:

```
MyModel.update_all([%(data = data || hstore(?,?)), 'a', 'new_value']))
```

The core fix for this was wrapping the update_all action in a [] and %(). I am still struggling to figure out how the %() defines the SET in the Postgre SQL so if anyone has an explanation that would be uber-helpful.

In my case I was actually removing a key too (really I wanted to update the key name but keep the value). So if anyone has that issue the code looks like:

```
MyModel.update_all([%(data = delete("data",?)), 'a'])
```

I was hoping to do both actions in the same call but that was creating a really odd command in the SQL where the second action was added as part of the WHERE clause not the SET. Still a bit of black magic for me but hopefully this helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you use

`MyModel.update_all(:properties => ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore.dump({'a' => 1}))`

then it will cleared out other values and if you try to use

`MyModel.update_all("data = data || hstore('a', 'blah')")` it will only work if there is any value in hstore column,
so try to use combination of both

`if (hstore_column_name).present? 
    MyModel.update_all("data = data || hstore('a', 'blah')") 
else
    MyModel.update_all(:properties => ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore.dump({'a' => 1}))`